# C#:How to get the longest common prefix from a list of strings LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to learn LINQ
I would like to understand how to get the longest common prefix from a list of strings
{"a","abC","abcD"}
would return "ab". Common as in at least 1 other string has it. Even though "a" is common for all 3, I would like to get "ab" because 2 elements share this prefix and "ab" is longer than "a"

Comment: Can you post your definition of *longest common prefix*? And the code you have written for this? -- Based on my knowledge, the prefix should be `a`.

Comment: Sorry for being ambiguous. I want to get the longest prefix that is shared by at least 2 strings. "a" is common for all 3 elements, "ab" only for 2,but since it is longer than "a", "ab" should be returned.

Comment: Well, this is not exactly the definition of *longest common prefix*. -- Instead of taking the first and last string from the array sorted in ascending order, take the last two (very specific to what you have posted here). -- Note that you need to post the code that you have tried to write for this.

Comment: A radix tree would do brilliantly here, but there is no built in implementation of it. Why doesn't `abc` count, are you ignoring case or not?

Comment: it is case sensitive. abC is different from abc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an interesting challenge and this is my solution:

```cs
var array = new []{"a","abC","abcD"};

var longestCommonPrefix = Enumerable.Range(1, array.Max(_ => _)!.Length)
            .Select(i =>
            {
                var grouped = array.Where(x => x.Length >= i)
                    .GroupBy(x => x[..i])
                    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
                    .Select(x => new { LongestCommonPrefix = x.Key })
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                return grouped?.LongestCommonPrefix ?? string.Empty;
            }).Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var longestCommonPrefix = (words.FirstOrDefault() ?? String.Empty)
    .Substring(0,
      Enumerable.Range(0, words.Any() ? words.Min(x => x.Length) + 1 : 0)
       .Where(x => words.Select(w => w.Substring(0, x))
                     .Distinct().Count() == 1).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max()
      );
```